# How to calculate memory usage as a percent from docker api i.e /containers/{id}/stats

Tags: docker

When using the docker API /containers/{id}/stats I am able to get memory usage from the json file under memory stats.

```
"memory_stats": {
"stats": {},
"max_usage": 6651904,
"usage": 6537216,
"failcnt": 0,
"limit": 67108864
},
```

The question is, how do you calculate the percent memory usage for the container from this? Have googled for any documentation on this but not able to get any.

Answer (score 3):

This won't give the same answer as fetched by the Docker stats command.
Docker uses multiple combinations to arrive at MEM%, according to my calculations you should take into consideration the cache and active memory as well

The formula would look something like:

```
def get_mem_perc(stats):
    mem_used = stats["memory_stats"]["usage"] - stats["memory_stats"]["stats"]["cache"] + stats["memory_stats"]["stats"]["active_file"]
    limit = stats['memory_stats']['limit']
    return round(mem_used / limit * 100, 2)
```

Where stats are the stats value for the entire container

Answer (score 1):

docker is open source, which means we can look at the source code :)

Just parse through the `json object` and divide `usage` by the `limit`. Keep in mind, that the limit is the limit of the entire host machine, and exceeding this will result in an OOM kill.

This is also what's displayed when running `docker stats` and looking at `MEM USAGE / LIMIT` and `MEM %`

```py
return float(json_object['memory_stats']['usage']) / float(json_object['memory_stats']['limit']) * 100)
```

Confirmed by looking at the open source repo [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/eb131c5383db8cac633919f82abad86c99bffbe5/cli/command/container/stats_helpers.go#L110)